# Problem with an querying an array. (MySQL/PHP)

Tags: mysql

I have an array of strings inputted by the user from an dynamic form. I want to store each value of the array into a table along with an itemid (which is the same for all)

My query is currently inserting the whole array into one row's text_value with implode.

Is there a way instead of looping through the array and running a query for each value in the array, for me to query each array value with the itemId.

I was thinking perhaps adding another dimension to the array with the itemId? is this possible?

current query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO answers_tb (item_id, text_value)VALUES('$itemid','".implode(',', $answers) . "')";
```

here is print_r of array:

Array ( [0] => option 1 [1] => option 2 [2] => option 3 [3] => option 4 )

here is the table structure I am inserting to (item_id is a foreign key):

```
**Field**  | **Type**   **Attributes**      
answer_id  | int(11)    PRIMARY KEY 
item_id    | int(11)    FOREIGN KEY                 
text_value | varchar(50)
```

the referenced table:

```
**Field**       | **Type**        | **Attributes**  
item_id      | int(11)    |       PRIMARY KEY               
item_type    | tinyint(1)     |     
user_id      | int(11)    |     
unit_id      | int(11)    |     
question_text    | varchar(100)             
question_text_2  | varchar(100)             
item_desc    | varchar(25)          
item_name    | varchar(25)
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would be better served with a different table design.

Instead of `answers_tb (item_id, text_value)`, use `answers_tb (item_id, offset, value)`.

(The primary key would be `(item_id, offset)`.)

Then you would find it much easier to query the table.

EDIT: You posted the following table structure:

```
**Field**  | **Type**   **Attributes**
answer_id  | int(11)    PRIMARY KEY
item_id    | int(11)    FOREIGN KEY
text_value | varchar(50)
```

If I understand the table design right, your design works like this:

- Each row of the referenced table (let's call it `questions`) represents a single question asked by a user of your application. It has a question ID, and the ID of the user who posted it.
- Each row of the table `answers_tb` represents the set of all answers to the question in the row of table `questions` referenced by `item_id`. Answers are distinguished by the order in which they appear in the column entry.

What I'm saying is that this design for `answers_tb` doesn't work very well, for the reason you've identified: it's difficult to query against the answers stored in the "array" column. That is why this design is problematic. A better design would be as follows:

```
**Field**     | **Type**
item_id       | int(11)
answer_number | int
text_value    | varchar(50)
```

wherein `item_id` is still a foreign key, but the primary key is `(item_id, answer_number)`. In this design, each row of the table, rather than containing the set of all answers to the corresponding question, would contain just one answer to that question. The rows are distinguished from one another by the different values in `answer_number`, but you know which question each row corresponds to by the value in `item_id`. This design is much easier to query against.

It is a general rule that you ought not to try to store an array of data in a column, because it makes it problematic to search against. In some cases it makes sense to break that rule, but you have to be able to recognise when you are in such a case. In this case, you want to search by the stored values, so you should not do it.

Comment: well the item_id is just a foreign key. The table is constructed of answer_id, text_value, item_id. I don't quite understand the whole offset thing. I am new to this stuff.

Comment: "offset" refers to the numbering of the items in the array. The first item has offset 0, the second item has offset 1, etc. A given column can be (part of) a foreign key but also (part of) the primary key. If you post the exact structure of the table, along with the structure of the referenced table, I could give clearer advice.

Comment: i have edited my post with basic contents structure of table or what i think you want?

Comment: I need to know the primary key, etc. also. Could you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table, and also for the table referenced by the foreign key.

Comment: @Hammerite Apologies I didnt reply yesteday. The uni lab closed yesterday. I have updated my post.

Comment: what ive done which works is construct a 2d array (in a foreach loop on the $answers array) with the first column all as $item_id and second column individual strings from 1d array. Then imploded this in my query. I am assuming I am doing a complete bodge job of it :D

Answer (score 0):

If you structure your table as `item_id, astring` rather than `item_id, alongconcatenatedstring`, you could do the insert like this:

```
$id=2;
$valueclause=function($string) use ($id) { return "('$id','$string')";};
array_walk($valueclause, $arr);

$values=implode(',',$arr);
$query= "INSERT INTO  answers_tb (item_id, text_value) VALUES $values";
```

ETA: It appears that it might be useful to have a primary key that combines an auto_increment and another column.  So given your table struture of:

```
         **Field**  | **Type**
         answer_id  | int(11)
         item_id    | int(11)
         text_value | varchar(50)
```

you might consider indexing like this:

```
CREATE TABLE answers_tb(
    item_id INT NOT NULL,
    answer_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    text_value CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id, answer_id)//note the 2 columns in the key
);
```

Then when you insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO  answers_tb (item_id, text_value) 
VALUES (1,'thing'), (1,'foo'), 
       (17,'blah'), 
       (6,'beebel'), (6,'bar');
```

your resulting data will look like this:

```
item_id, answer_id, textvalue
1,       1,         thing
1,       2,         foo
17,      1,         blah
6,       1,         beebel
6,       2,         bar
```

Comment: I do my table to answer_id, item_id (FK), text_value. I already have an array of just the strings which is $answers.

Comment: @buymypies: your current query has a VALUES clause like this: `VALUES ('id','string1','string2','string3)`, a single row insert.  The above gives a VALUES clause of `VALUES ('id','string1'),('id','string2'),('id','string3')`, a multi-row insert

Comment: sorry I didnt reply, sooner, my uni lab closed and kicked me out :( I am struggling to understand your post, I think I get your insert, however how would that work with an array of strings? It will always be the case that all the strings (single dimension array) being inserted will have the same itemId (question) they will be attached to.

Comment: @buymypies: because the answer_id is an auto_increment, each subsequent string with the same item_id gets a unique answer_id. You don't insert as an array of strings with 1 item_id; you insert as (item_id, singlestring) pairs where the item_id is constant.